# While quoting someone's statement, does the placement of "S/he said" matter?

Tags: sentence-structure, direct-speech

Look at these sentences -

> ***Veronica said,*** "I'm not gonna give up for sure." **OVER** 
>   *"I'm not gonna give up for sure"*, **said Veronica**.

A person (a non native) said that putting *said Veronica* makes a sentence a bit authoritative or impactful! I wonder that.

Is there any context where we prefer *someone said* over *said someone*? Is that non-native speaker right?

Kindly give your opinions.

Comment: There's a third alternative: *"I'm not gonna give up for sure", **Veronica said***.

Comment: So there are really two things going on here: (1) the position of the speech tag, and (2) moving the subject after the verb.  This is covered grammatically in CGEL on pp.1026-7, though it doesn't answer your question about subjective impressions (e.g. "authoritative or impactful").

Comment: @snailplane I don't have CGEL. Would you mind telling me that?

Comment: My comment above was actually an attempt at summarizing the key information already :-)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is identical, but in a piece of factual writing such as a news report you would usually see the form ***Veronica said...***.

This version would probably also be preferred if you are introducing Veronica for the first time in your writing, or emphasising the fact that *Veronica* said it, e.g.:

> I asked my friends to name the world's best footballer. "It's got to be Messi," said Dale. Veronica said, "No way! What about Agüero?"

In descriptive writing or fiction you could use whichever form you prefer, perhaps using both to create variety as in the example above.

Comment: so it *has* to do something with *emphasizing*, hasn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you want to emphasise 'Veronica' I think you need to use the form 'Veronica said', but you can also use that form without implying any emphasis.